# ckeditor - remove tag with specific value of attribute

Tags: ckeditor

is there any way how to remove tag from editor if match value in attribute?
For example:
image with source
`<img src="file:///C:/something/something/something.png" alt="xxx">`
if match file:///.... then it will remove whole tag from editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor', {
height: 500, 
allowedContent: {
'p img[!src,alt,align,width,height]':true,

'img': { 
    match: function( element ) {
            var patt = /file:\/\//i;
            return element.attributes[ 'src' ]!== undefined ? (
                 !patt.test(element.attributes[ 'src' ]) 

                ) :  true;
        },
        attributes: 'src,height,width,alt,hspace,vspace,align,border',
        styles:'*'
    },
},


} );
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yobrucfg/

Comment: I've just found out, that image2 plugin doesn't work correctly.
Resize doesn't work and add new image dialog window has only 2 inputs (link, alt), width and height aren't there.
Do you have any fix for this?

Comment: Sorry, i don't use image2 plugin. Check this http://ckeditor.com/addon/base64image